# How to change body padding of the windows in ExtJS Triton?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a window with a tabpanel in it. It's really annoying how the window has its 5px padding. I try to override all the paddings of the window, but has no effect on it. And it's same with a grid in a window as well.

```
Ext.window.Window.override({
    padding: 0,
    bodyPadding: 0,
    style: {
        padding: 0
    }
});
```

[image: window tabpanel padding]

Thank you, if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I colored the background, and minimized the border, now it looks a little better

```
style: {
    backgroundColor: "#5fa2dd",
    borderWidth: "0px"
}
```

Comment: But it's not the solution. When it's not a tabpanel or grid, this 5px resizer padding is on the inner panels...